# oracle grouping everytime the sum amount is below 15

Tags: sql, oracle

I've following data:

```
SELECT 1 note, 1000 amt FROM dual union all
SELECT 2 note, 2000 amt FROM dual union all
SELECT 3 note, 8000 amt FROM dual union all
SELECT 4 note, 3000 amt FROM dual union all
SELECT 5 note, 1500 amt FROM dual union all
SELECT 6 note, 1600 amt FROM dual union all
SELECT 7 note, 20000 amt FROM dual union all
SELECT 8 note, 20000 amt FROM dual union all
SELECT 9 note, 2100 amt FROM dual union all
SELECT 10 note, 4500 amt FROM dual union all
SELECT 11 note, 1000 amt FROM dual union all
SELECT 12 note, 16000 amt FROM dual
```

and I need sum the amount, but for every sum <= 15000, they will be grouped together. If the amount is > 15000, they will be on their own group like this:

| NOTE | AMT | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 1 |
| 11 | 1000 | 1 |
| 5 | 1500 | 1 |
| 6 | 1600 | 1 |
| 2 | 2000 | 1 |
| 9 | 2100 | 1 |
| 4 | 3000 | 1 |
| 10 | 4500 | 2 |
| 3 | 8000 | 2 |
| 12 | 16000 | 3 |
| 7 | 20000 | 4 |
| 8 | 20000 | 5 |

I need the solution in oracle sql, is it possible? I'm using oracle 11g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is a recursive subquery:

```
with tt(note, amt, seqnum) as (
      select t.note, t.amt, row_number() over (order by amt) as seqnum
      from t
     ),
     cte(note, amt, seqnum, grp, running_amt) as (
      select note, amt, seqnum, 1, amt
      from tt
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select tt.note, tt.amt, tt.seqnum,
             (case when tt.amt + cte.running_amt > 15000 then cte.grp + 1 else cte.grp end),
             (case when tt.amt + cte.running_amt > 15000 then tt.amt else tt.amt + cte.running_amt end)
      from cte join
           tt
           on tt.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8b652da3e4f35e4cf0e3a8f0d365ca91) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  This is ordering by `amt` -- as in your sample data.  You can as easily order by `note` (which also makes sense) just by adjusting `seqnum` in `tt`.

Comment: wow thanks! I don't even think about it this way. One question, performance wise, is this method will take a lot of resources?

Comment: I think due to self join and union this could be in theory a bit slower than plain MATCH_RECOGNIZE. But most likely you will not notice any difference.

Comment: Depending whether "Oracle 11g" means version 11.1 or 11.2 recursive subquery is not available either. They have been introduced in 11.2.

Comment: I see, actually I used 11.2, but somehow MATCH_RECOGNIZE is not working in mine. I think I will stick to your solution. Thanks!

Comment: @rgprakoso . . . You should accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SQL for Pattern Matching](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm#DWHSG8956):

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 1 note, 1000 amt FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 note, 2000 amt FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 note, 8000 amt FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 note, 3000 amt FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 note, 1500 amt FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 note, 1600 amt FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 note, 20000 amt FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 note, 20000 amt FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 note, 2100 amt FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 note, 4500 amt FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 note, 1000 amt FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 12 note, 16000 amt FROM DUAL)
SELECT note, amt, amt_group, sum_amt
FROM t
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    ORDER BY amt
    MEASURES 
        MATCH_NUMBER() AS amt_group,
        NVL(SUM(amt), amt) AS sum_amt
    ALL ROWS PER MATCH
    PATTERN (s*)
    DEFINE
        s AS SUM(amt) <= 15000
    ) mr
ORDER BY amt
```

| NOTE | AMT | AMT_GROUP | SUM_AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 1 | 1000 |
| 11 | 1000 | 1 | 2000 |
| 5 | 1500 | 1 | 3500 |
| 6 | 1600 | 1 | 5100 |
| 2 | 2000 | 1 | 7100 |
| 9 | 2100 | 1 | 9200 |
| 4 | 3000 | 1 | 12200 |
| 10 | 4500 | 2 | 4500 |
| 3 | 8000 | 2 | 12500 |
| 12 | 16000 | 3 | 16000 |
| 7 | 20000 | 4 | 20000 |
| 8 | 20000 | 5 | 20000 |

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, I just know about this match_recognized thing. But when I tried it in my server, it always return error for ORA-00933. Any idea why? I'm using 11g

Comment: MATCH_RECOGNIZE was introduced in Oracle 12.1. Meanwhile Oracle 11g is outdated, maybe it is time for an upgrade.

Comment: ah I see, that's explain the error I got. thanks for the information!